# American's use of the word "socialism"

Tags: united-states, terminology, socialism

I have long been confused by many American's use of the word "socialism". AFAICT they appear to use it to mean communism... in which case, what word(s) would an American use to describe the economic/political systems used in Sweden, Germany, the UK and even the US itself?

Comment: While some of the answers are more narrowly focused on Sanders, [BurnsBA’s answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/38974/19301) deals with your question nicely

Comment: The Sanders question is interesting - and answers my question to a large degree... but still - if an american said to me "socialism is awful, just look at Cuba" for example... and I said "but what about Germany, is that socialist too?" What would they say? Or if I said "Tell me some countries that aren't socialist" what would they say?

Comment: _[W]hat word(s) would an American use to describe the economic/political systems used in Sweden, Germany, the UK and even the US itself?_ This American uses _welfare statism_, most don't. See, [Welfare state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welfare_state).

Comment: @Mick These other questions might further help you out: [How do I explain democratic socialism to an American?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/9267/19301), [What is a simple concise way to explain the difference between socialism and communism to others](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/49847/19301)

Comment: @Mick: Many Americans would say that Germany looks pretty bad, too :-)